# CvANN_MLP::write in OpenCV creates large XML file. How can I reduce its size by reducing the precision of real numbers in the file?

Tags: xml, opencv

I generate an XML file containing trained neural network using CvANN_MLP::write method in OpenCV, but it creates very large file. When I see the content of the generated file, it contains real numbers with many digits after the decimal point. I do not need so much precision and want to reduce the file size by making the precision up to only 6 digits after decimal point. Would any one please tell me how to reduce the precision of real numbers in the file? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XML Files tend to be bloated regardless of what you put in them. How about going for a slimmer option such as Json?

I like using Rapid Json. It is in C but written very well easy to use and integrate and only limited by BSD license.

If you wish here is an example where I make use of [Rapid Json](https://bitbucket.org/YontanSimson/opencv-projects/src/a40437bcf7eb93bd99a470e345deb0078d2da61a/ChanVese/?at=master)

Pay specific attention to DataType.h where I wrote a nice interface for reading Json Parameters.

Here is also a demo for you to see how easy it is to use Rapid Json [Example](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/source/browse/branches/version0.1x/example/tutorial/tutorial.cpp?r=91)

Comment: the XML format is not the issue as there are very few tags to a nnetwork file. The issue is the sheer size of the floating point number data. Switching to json would be of negligible gain